# Error while Executing jupyter notebook: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have installed anaconda, when I type jupyter notebook, I have got below error.

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

after a lot of google search found below command 
 (it is for Python 3)

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

above command will reinstall everything from PyPi. .even after executing this I have faced below error

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/attrs-19.1.0.dist-info'
```

can you help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I tried many things but simple "sudo" command prefixing to the original command helped me to fixed this issue.

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!.

Answer (score 0):

IPython is causing this issue. So uninstalling it would be a better option.

```
sudo apt-get remove ipython
sudo apt-get purge ipython
sudo apt-get autoremove
pip install jupyter
```

Now execute jupyter notebook command...